# Selenium Javascript move slider not working

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium Javascript

```
            driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css(".handle.handler1")), 5000);
    var slider = driver.findElement(By.css(".handle.handler1"));
    slider.then(function (elem) {
        driver.actions().dragAndDrop(elem, {x: 25, y: 0}).perform();
    });
```

I tried to put this code in loop and I see slider is selected but it does not move

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: <div class="handle handler1"></div>

Comment: Do provide the link to the webpage under test or framework used for the application